# Errors with Connect String in C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have fixed the connection string, so it give me errors show here:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

The password in microsoft SQL Server has worked also, and in `service.msc` `MSSQLSERVER` is running, but Visual Studio shows errors.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Learn_App_Login
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //khai bao bien
        private SqlConnection InitCon;
        private SqlCommand cmd;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //ham ket noi database 
        public static SqlConnection GetCon()
        {
            string strcon = @"data source=LAPTOP-AFR31CFM.;
            initial catalog ='SaleDB';
            user id='LAPTOP-AFR31CFM\D4RKDR4G0N'; password='12@#!';
            Integrated Security=true;";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            return con;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {      
            SqlConnection connectionToServer = new SqlConnection();

            SqlConnection con = GetCon();
            con.Open();

            string sqlSelect = "select * from account" +
                               "Where username ='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and password ='" + txtPassword.Text + " ' ";

            // khoi tao doi tuong command
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect,con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            //khoi tao doi tuong adapter
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            //tao datable chua data
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            //su dung adapter do data vao table nay
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            //binding eridview voi table
            dgwAccount.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That point after the Data Source's value is suspect. Do you really have that name or it is just a typo?

Comment: Is your database on localhost or on a network?

Comment: If you use integrated security, then your user ID and password will be ignored (i think).

Comment: @SMor if I remove the security can that work?

Comment: @ImanNemati yes, it is in the localhost.

Comment: If you're using integrated security, don't declare the username and password. You can't provide a Windows username and password for a connection the way you have; you'd need to use SQL Login instead.

Comment: For Windows authentication to the default instance on the local host, you can use `data source=.;initial catalog ='SaleDB';Integrated Security=SSPI;`

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks you, the code gives me can working better than, but after it, I back to first errors :(: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '='.'

Comment: @PhạmThông, add a space after the table name like the answer to your other question. Also use a parameterized query, unless you want to fail your class when someone enters `';DROP TABLE account;--` in the username text box.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error. It says that your database doesn’t exist.

Or for some reason the computer the code was running on could not communicate with the SQL Server. This could be caused by a lot of things: Firewall issues, DNS/Name resolution, SQL Configuration (not configured to accept TCP/IP connection)

Comment: in the microsoft it give me all working but I don't know why it give me here, and I has checked the firewall it all off, how can I have solutions for that?